# SOLVED - Raspberry pi (running ubuntu 14.04) citrix problem

Tags: pi-2, hdmi, ubuntu

I have a problem running Citrix receiver on my raspberry pi 2B running Ubuntu 14.04 lxde custom spin off (it litteraly only has the core essentials of LXDE and firefox that's it oh and lightdm)

It was designed to be a Thin Client (I know its possible), so I installed Citrix Receiver.

It connects, disconnects reconnect you are able to use the apps inside the VM (XenApp) (Windows 2008 R2)

The problem is when you ALT+Tab to a different window (full screen to full screen) you only see parts of the new window and the old one, when you press the new window bit with the mouse the old part disappears.

So I ran a test to see what was troubling it, the CPU is only 54.2% under load, the screen response time is 72MS (im used to way more so no worries there) the receival of the data is OK aswell as sending it, but what bothers me is the FPS, the max fps I got on a HDMI to VGA converter connected screen was 14.0 FPS, and on a direct HDMI TV of the same resolution I had 20 FPS Max, I tried everything posted on the Citrix forums already, so I turn to you guys, maybe you know what the solution to this problem is?

These are the results of the citrix test

```
DD=Off, BD=On, FL=Off, H264=Off
startup time: wed Aug 3 15:55:45 2016
Server address: *snip*
Session size: 1920x1080
thread info: CH 12 [64KB], CH 9 [128KB]
frames: 4140, Frame Rate: 14.0 FPS
data recv: 7304 KB @ 0.3 KB/s (peak 281.7)
data sent: 92 KB @ 0.4 KB/s (peak 1.0)
cpu 54.2% [60.2% 84.0% 52.5% 56.9%]
jpeg rate: 0.0 Mp/s (0.0/s) (peak 1.6)
rle rate: 0.0 Mp/s (8.0/s) (peak 2.4)
Screen respone time: 72 ms (peak 520)
```

**---------------------------EDIT---------------------------**

Could the differences be the OS? I made it as minimal as I could get (1.6 GB on a 8 GB sd card) but I saw a screen shot of someone playing a game on a NUC running ThinOS getting solid 55 FPS? what could this be..

**---------------------------EDIT2---------------------------**

[This is what I mean with my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7hLe.png)

**---------------------------EDIT3---------------------------**

Upon experimenting with a different VM (newer version running Windows server 2012 r2) I found to still have the EXACT same problem but the FPS was skyrocketing on a solid 30/40 FPS, so FPS is out of the equation... here, beneath this edit you will see the terminal output of the test on the Ws 2012 r2 version compared to the ws2008 r2 version

**---------------------------Comparison---------------------------**

Left = 2008 r2 (locally but in same building)

Right = 2012 r2 (locally but in same building)

```
DD=Off, BD=On, FL=Off, H264=Off                 |    DD=Off, BD=On, FL=Off, H264=Off
startup time: wed Aug 3 15:55:45 2016           |    startup time: Thu Aug 4 09:20:43 2016  
Server address: *snip*                          |    Server address: *snip* 
Session size: 1920x1080                         |    Session size: 1920x1080
thread info: CH 12 [64KB], CH 9 [128KB]         |    thread info: CH 12 [64KB], CH 9 [128KB]
frames: 4140, Frame Rate: 14.0 FPS              |    frames: 429, Frame Rate: 29.0 FPS 
data recv: 7304 KB @ 0.3 KB/s (peak 281.7)      |    Data recv: 4790@368.7 KB/s (peak 620.6)
data sent: 92 KB @ 0.4 KB/s (peak 1.0)          |    data sent: 27 KB @ 1.4 KB/s (peak 1.5)
cpu 54.2% [60.2% 84.0% 52.5% 56.9%]             |    cpu 63.0% [61.5%, 64.3%, 65.3% 62.1%]
jpeg rate: 0.0 Mp/s (0.0/s) (peak 1.6)          |    jpeg rate: 0.5 Mp/s (75.9/s) (peak 3.2)
rle rate: 0.0 Mp/s (8.0/s) (peak 2.4)           |    rle rate: 7.6 Mp/s (2980.0/s) (peak 8.0)
Screen respone time: 72 ms (peak 520)           |    Screen Response time: 60MS (peak 60)
```

**---------------------------EDIT4---------------------------**

Second test for today, I was interested to see if maybe the Desktop environment (LXDE) was taking too much Ram/ Video ram from the pi and thus caused the visual glitching, so I restarted, this time using the Ubuntu 14.04 minimal image like before but only installing openbox for a true minimalistic OS, this has proven succesfull in a 3 minute test so far, going to monitor it longer for today

**---------------------------EDIT5---------------------------**

SUCCESS! for now atleast, the raspberry pi (which i am using to post this edit) running citrix receiver, connected to XenAPP Running windows server 2008 r2 is working solidly for now, going to test it the rest of the work day to see if there is any 'anomoly', the funniest thing? it uses almost as much of ram and SD card space as the custom fully fledged Desktop OS.

I'll be posting updates spread of the rest of the day, one now, one at 2 PM and one at 5 PM (when work is over so can be a tad later) and ill decide tomorrow if this was to solution or not STAY TUNED FOR UPDATES!

**--------------------------- Update 1 ---------------------------**

Still works, still going strong, hurray

**--------------------------- Update 2 ---------------------------**

I got it working it seems like LXDE used too much? I don't know... from my results from my system scanner (it shows everything of the system like ram hdd usage etc etc, it shows that openbox alone with tint2, citrix receiver and firefox use 1.2gb HDD space and 264,2 MB, guess.. that's that?

**--------------------------- Conclusion! ---------------------------**

My conclusion is that somehow LXDE (even though with XFCE4 it was heavier) uses too much Video memory, this mean that not enough memory can be passed to the citrix receiver thus causing the visual glitching.

**--------------------------- Advice! ---------------------------**

The glitching can be very annoying and on top of that reduce productivity of your employee.

if you want to use the raspberry pi as a Thin client, don't do what I did, wasting many precious hours trying to figure out a problem while the answer is right infront of you, if you want to use this, ONLY install Openbox, firefox and citrix.

Answer (score 0):

My conclusion is that somehow LXDE (even though with XFCE4 it was heavier) uses too much Video memory, this mean that not enough memory can be passed to the citrix receiver thus causing the visual glitching.

The glitching can be very annoying and on top of that reduce productivity of your employee.

if you want to use the raspberry pi as a Thin client, don't do what I did, wasting many precious hours trying to figure out a problem while the answer is right infront of you, if you want to use this, ONLY install Openbox, firefox and citrix.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.